# Value gets lost between initialization and retrieval

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

(ASP.NET MVC4 on Visual Studio 12 using Identity Framework)
Please, I wish someone could explain this to me.
*This is a second case. The first one is described under **Edit 1***

I am getting a weird situation.

## Edit 2 (new)

In my initialization file, after all the initializing is done and right before committing the changes to `DataContext`, each of the `Student` objects has `Courses.Count()` greater than `0`, i.e. `5` or `4`

```
bob.Courses.Count();
mary.Courses.Count();
wei.Courses.Count();
john.Courses.Count();
jack.Courses.Count();
jill.Courses.Count();

dc.SaveChanges();
```

Moments later, however, when I am trying to query them like this ...

```
var studentsCount = dc.Students.Count();
foreach (var st in dc.Students.ToList()) {
   var coursesCount = st.Courses.Count(); // THIS LINE!!!
   foreach (var crs in st.Courses.ToList()) {
       if (crs.CourseId == cancellation.CourseBase.CourseId) {
           var user = manager.FindByName(st.UserName);
           cancellation.Users.Add(user);
       }
   }
}
```

...the line `var coursesCount = st.Courses.Count();` is returning `0`!
I have no idea why. Do the values get lost somewhere in between?

---

## Edit 1

I initialize my `Course` object by hard-coding the values.
When I am debugging, I can see all the fields in the `Course` object have values, and no value is `null`.
**However**,
When I query like this:

```
var courses = dc.Courses.ToList().Where(course => course.User.Id ==currentUserId);
                                                  *
```

and debug, I see that one of the fields is suddenly `null`.
It looks like the value gets lost somewhere in between the initialization and retrieval!
Has anyone come across this before?

Tell me if you need to see more code.

Comment: Note that `dc.Courses.ToList().Where(course => course.User.Id ==currentUserId)` is going to be very hard on your server. Do `dc.Courses.Where(course => course.User.Id ==currentUserId).ToList()` instead, that will get only the needed records from the server instead of getting them all then throwing away the results you don't need.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am trying that out now! :)